# Collection of pointers to different objects with polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a virtual base class B and derived classes D1 and D2. I have virtual method in B and i have overridden that method in D1 and D2. I now want to have a list containing pointers to objects from both D1 and D2. Naturally i declare that pointer as B*. Let me say in advance that all copying of objects from class B and its derived classes are prohibited. I want to have effects of polymorphism in this list. One method i have seen is to have a virtual "clone" method in B and override that method in D1 and D2 so that it returns pointers to D1 and D2. But i cannot do this because all copying is prohibited (and my copy constructor is deleted)

```
class B {
  protected:
   double payment;
  public:
   virtual void getPayment() const = 0;
   virtual B* copy() const = 0;
   B(const B&) = delete;
   B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
};

class D1: public B {
 public:
  double getPayment() const override { return payment*2;}
  D1* copy() { return new D1(*this); } // This wont work because copying is prohibited
};

class D2: public B {
 public:
  double getPayment() const override { return payment*4;}
  D2* copy() { return new D2(*this); } // This wont work because copying is prohibited
};

int main() {

struct Elem {
  B* b;
  Elem* next = nullptr;
  Elem(const B& b1): b(b1.copy()) {}; // This wont work because copying is prohibited
  ~Elem() {delete b;}
};
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?
One thing i came up with is to always check if object is type D1 or D2 and then dynamicly convert pointer but this seems extremely opposite of what polymorphism is supposed to do.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to do, but if you want just an Pointer of type `B*` that points to an object of type `D1`, you can do `B* d_ptr = static_cast<B*>(d_ptr);`. To not leak memory, you should consider using smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @n314159 i want that every time i go through list every element of the list uses its own method getPayment depending on which class the pointer points to. That example is helpful for smaller cases but if i have 100 kinds of derived classes it would be hard to pull of

Comment: Where do you get the pointers from? Just put the pointers of type `D1*` or `D2*` in a list containing type `B*` it will all work as you want it to.

Comment: Why not remove the methods that don't work? What can't you do without them that you need to do? You can have a `B*`, a `std::unique_ptr<B>` or whatever you want and manipulate them polymorphically. Just don't copy them.

Comment: Implement a proper copy-constructor, or don't copy them. This question is very unclear. You want to copy something that you can't copy? You can copy it, but there is no copy-constructor for some other reason?

Comment: So if you don't want to copy anything, then is there any reason you can't just do `Elem(B* b1): b(b1) {};` for the Elem constructor?

Comment: I still used and commented usage of copy constructors even though they dont work just to show what i would like to do. For some reason i thought that just passing the pointer to object from either D1 or D2 class would result in disabling polymorphism. I need to check my sources again.

Comment: That’s not a virtual base class, but a *polymorphic* one.

Comment: What do you mean by _"effects of polymorphism"_ (that you want to have in your list)? Can you give a [mcve] that demonstrates *not* having the effect you want?